# How can i display a CheckMark when item is selected in menu item?

Tags: office-ui-fabric

I'm using **DefaultButton** control from office ui fabric, i want to show a check mark when a item is selected in menu item of button. How can i bring this in office-ui-fabric component.
in below picture   is showing menu item and when user choose any menu item checkbox should be appear.
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric#/controls/web/button

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [codepen](https://codepen.io/vitalius1/pen/zYxOzwp) that demonstrates how to use the checkmark on an item in the menu attached to a Fabric `DefaultButton`. The gist is that when providing the array of menu items you need to specify that the item can check and with the item property `canCheck`. Also, in order to have the checkmark rendered on selection you need to maintain a state of the current selected items and subsequently map that state to each individual item through the `isChecked` property.